# What was Mac OS 9 built on?

Tags: mac, classic-mac-os

I am interested in old school technology. The Mac OS X is based on UNIX. I am interested in the old school OS, Mac OS 9, what is this based on? Can it run the UNIX application? What is the file system in Mac OS 9?

Answer (score 4):

This should cover everything you're looking for: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Mac_OS

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) is a good place to start reading about Mac history.